# How to sending forgot password mail without using auth in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forgot-password

i try to create custom forgot password class but my class and method not working, plz help me my code

```
   function sendResetEmail($email, $tokenData){

    $user = DB::table('forgot_password')->where('email', $email)->select('email')->first();

    
    $link = config('base_url') . 'password/reset/' . $tokenData . '?email=' . urlencode($user->email);

        Mail::send('Customers.forgot_password',['token' => $tokenData], function($message) use ($user) {
              $message->from($user->email);
              $message->to('mymail@gmail.com');
              $message->subject('Reset Password Notification');
           });

}
```

Comment: Any problem with your code? What an error?

Comment: mail not send, thank for comment

Comment: is it controller? Can you more describe your problem, tell us what steps you did?

Comment: i use my create login and registration system, i try to create custom password reset class but i can not create custom reset password class.

Comment: Most developers use Oath but I want to use my own code

Comment: I can share my project with you ?